# Access forbidden on apache2 on ubuntu14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed apache2 server on Ubuntu 14.04. It is working well with the files and directories which i have created here after installation, but if i copy any file or folder from anywhere else (already written) then is gives **Forbidden** error message.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a file to be accessible by apache2, it should be owned by the user which runs the apache2 server. On most systems the user is www-data or httpd or apache. To find which user is that, just look into your apache2.conf or httpd.conf. Once you know the user, make it the owner of the copied files/folders or reiterate it for the whole /var/www//html folder.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

This should do it. But, if it doesn't, verify that the user has at least read and execute permissions on the folder (write also, if you need to write some data through your script).